# Save entity with subresource into redis with Symfony & Api Platform

Tags: symfony, redis, doctrine, symfony4, api-platform.com

I have 2 entities, Event & User. So basically A user can have multiple event.
I have an EventItemDataProvider and in the getItem method I did something like that:

```
public function getItem(string $resourceClass, $id, string $operationName = null, array $context = []): ?Event
{
    if ($event = $this->cache->get($id, Event::class)) {
        return $event;
    }
    $event = $this->em->getRepository(Event::class)->find($id);
    if($event) {
        $this->cache->set($id, $event, 120);
    }
    return $event;
}
```

When the data is returned without the cache I have this result that is correct with the right username:

```
{
  "@context": "/contexts/Event",
  "@id": "/events/20",
  "@type": "Event",
  "title": "new global event 3",
  "description": "A big global event 3",
  "createdAt": "2019-07-05T09:20:48+00:00",
  "owner": {
    "@id": "/users/3",
    "@type": "User",
    "username": "test3"
  }
}
```

But if I hit the same method a second time, it will retrieve the data from the cache (redis) but this time username will be empty like that:

```
{
  "@context": "/contexts/Event",
  "@id": "/events/20",
  "@type": "Event",
  "title": "new global event 3",
  "description": "A big global event 3",
  "createdAt": "2019-07-05T09:20:48+00:00",
  "owner": {
    "@id": "/users/3",
    "@type": "User",
    "username": ""
  }
}
```

Why is my username empty when I retrieve it from redis?

Basically my cache class has these methods:

```
public function get(string $uniq, string $className)
{
    $value = $this->cache->getItem('test_key')->get();
    return $value;
}

public function set(string $uniq, object $entity, int $expires = 60)
{
    $save = $this->cache->getItem('test_key');
    $save->set($entity);
    $save->expiresAfter($expires);
    $saved = $this->cache->save($save);
    return $saved;
}
```

The owner field in my Event entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="events")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 * @Groups({"event:read", "event:write", "event:update"})
 * @Assert\Valid()
 */
private $owner;
```

The username field in my User entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
 * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write", "user:update", "event:item:get", "event:update"})
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please provide a username")
 */
private $username;
```

My redis cache configuration:

```
cache:
    app: cache.adapter.redis
    default_redis_provider: "redis://redis"
    pools:
        custom.cache.entity:
            adapter: cache.app
            default_lifetime: 120
```

Why my username is filled when I retrieve it from Doctrine Repository but empty when I retrieve it from Redis?

With Xdebug I can see that if I retrieve the data from Doctrine I have something like that:
[image]

But if I retrieve the data from the cache I have something like that:
[image]

In this second case, *initializer* -> this seems infinite, so I think that the problem is probably here, but what should I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Hello RaKoDev, I'm facing the same concern todat.
Have you fixed yours ?
Thanks

Comment: I deactivated the cache. The project is not live.
Let me know if you find a solution :)

Comment: I think it is a bad idea to store something like a proxy in Redis, it contains Closures. Closures bind objects to code and temporary variables. There will probably be references to services in there that are no longer valid in next request. If you really want to cache Entity data that would be something for Doctrine to do, or some extension of Doctrine.